# Как фильтровать столько страниц в админ панели WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт на Wordpress, у которого около 6 страниц. Дело в том, что я использую плагин Polylang , и, как известно, он создает страницу на другом языке. Т.е проблема в том что когда надо перевести эти 6 страниц на 10 языках (а их будет в 3 раза больше), то создается огромное количество страниц, и, скажу честно, очень неудобно ими управлять. Есть ли какой то плагин для решения данной задачи, чтобы менеджеру было удобно управлять страницами в этом хаосе. Может, разделение по языкам, либо ещё какое-то? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Непонятно, откуда вообще такой вопрос. Polylang в админке выводит страницы в зависимости от выбранного языка, переключатель языка в админ-баре наверху страницы.

Comment: Люди создают сайты с тысячами товаров на 20 языках, и ничего.

Comment: @KAGGDesign , я хотел бы узнать как можно сделать более удобным. WordPress на странице Pages показывает все все страницы. Если предположить что их 8 на 40 языках, получается обширное. Да, ничего критичного тут нет, но можно ведь сделать лучше

Comment: Да выберите уже нужный флаг в переключателе, и будете видеть только страницы этого языка: https://monosnap.com/file/jy2rev6UT1APKb3xptFcmxzmkxpkEw

Comment: Спасибо большое , не знал про эту возможность ))